# Magnific Popup is not working

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

Not sure why the popup is not working.

Console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'magnificPopup' index.html:17
```

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css" />
        <script src="js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="demo" href="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">Demo</a>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.demo').magnificPopup({
            type: "image",
            });

        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include your scripts in reverse order

```
 <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
 </head>
```

jQuery should be always first to include.

And remove that trailing `,` from the type property

```
$('.demo').magnificPopup({
    type: "image" // <== comma shouldn't be here since there is nothing to initialize after this
});
```

Comment: Oh I really apologize.
I'm trying to fire the popup and I tried that before but it's not working. And now it's working. :|